# How to export data from Excel to SQL Azure?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql, azure

I know how to import data from SQL Azure into Excel

```
From Excel go to:

  - Data
  - From Other Sources
  - From SQL Server
```

I want to manually edit data and post it back to SQL Azure. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To import data from Excel to SQL Azure you'll need to connect to a local server and use Import/Export wizard, since it's not visible from the Azure connection.

when you connect to a local server go to tasks -> Import data and connect to Excel and your file:

[image]

Click Next and connect to your SQL Azure db:

[image]

And follow the wizard.

Here is also the video describing the whole process in detail with some tips: http://www.sqltrainingonline.com/microsoft-excel-to-windows-azure-sql-in-10-minutes/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can open the just Import-Wizard directly as it is a Standalone Program.
Just search for "SQL Server 2014 Import and Export Data" in your start Menu or open the DTSWizard.exe which should be located in you install directory under \DTS\Binn\

No need for all this complicated fiddling with the local database. Also no need to start up Management-Studio at all.

Comment: Are you sure? The OP was asking about a cloud based SQL instance which needed an intermediate step.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/spreadsheet-into-sql-data/9nh0w51xxqrm?cid=msft_web_search) from windows store to convert excel file into SQL script with data insertion.

Then I run SQL script on Azure server.

No local SQL is required.